# Setting css constant() or env() variables in chrome for debugging

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

I have CSS like:

```
#something {
  top: 0;
  top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
  top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

(that changes view on mobile browser)

Is there a way to set `safe-area-inset-top` value as `constant` or `env` variable in chrome on desktop to debug/tests?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better answer will come but for now the best I found is to simply use variables as a workaround:

```
:root {
  --safe-area-inset-top: 20px;
}

#something {
  top: 0;
  top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
  top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
  top: var(--safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work or have any impact on the variable - running Chrome 94

Comment: It is not changing the env variable. This is a workaround to use variable named '--safe-area-inset-top' and use it wherever you use env(). This way you can manipulate variable to simulate this in browser.